# shrink multi videos into specific time using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion

I have multiple videos with the different length. And The Desired output of All those video length is 58 seconds only.

Here I tried but don't know what's should i replace here *****

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS/(****/58);atempo=*****/58" output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS/(****/58);atempo=*****/58" output2.mp4
ffmpeg -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS/(****/58);atempo=*****/58" output3.mp4
```

the Desired output are not what i need. Because I can't know the length of those videos.

Comment: Would using this be sufficient? `ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:58 output.mp4` or are you specifically trying to speed up the video to match 58 seconds?

Comment: Yes of course , I trying to speed up the video to match 58 seconds without trim any part of video .

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes on Window..